# DataSource parameter in connection string yields "Keyword not supported"

Tags: c#, sql-server

My code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DataSource=a;InitialCatalog=b;User ID=c;Password=d");
```

And I get error:

```
Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.
```

What to do?

Comment: create an empty connection and then provide `conn.DataSource = a;` Whenever you have doubt that something is wrong. Create an empty object and then provide a property and see what problem was in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Data Source` is two words.

Answer (score 6):

The usage is:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be in this form:

```
Data Source=
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyword is "Data Source", with a blank.

Answer (score 2):

There is a space in between data and source   "Data Source=a;"